Request for heeds when using '_' <underscore> as identifier in C (and interop with other languages)
In a C language library I wrote, I found most of the operations are too verbose, so I tried to make it terse - through use of macros and by reserving the _  identifier.
As I understand, identifiers beginning with _ are reserved for the C standard, the implementation(s), and libraries; but _ alone is not mentioned. I sensibly guess that it can be used by the program (i.e. the application).
This practice isn't new, $_ is used in Perl quite often, and has lots of idioms. In Python and some shell/scripting languages, _ also refer to the value of the last expression.
Of course, I won't be interfacing scripting languages directly. What need to be taken care and note of when using a lexically-local _ identifier in C? and in some other system programming languages (e.g. Rust, C++)? What kind of interoperability problems can arise from this?

Identifier names don't survive compilation, so I don't see what kind of interaction between them and other languages you have in mind.

_ is legal in C at block scope. _ is also the official placeholder identifier (which can be redefined, not just redeclared) in C++26 (Commenting about C++ since the question body mentions "e.g. Rust, C++")

"but _ alone is not mentioned" If the only character is an underscore, that is also the first character. That means, a single underscore is an identifier starting with underscore. And as such it should be reserved.

I looked at your library headers, and I think your attempt to make terse versions of functions and types is a bad idea. It fragments the API for no practical benefit, especially considering that the original names are already very short.

@user694733 The biggest motive for me to make 1st argument implicit is to achieve some syntax sugar like "unwrap chaining", such as those found in the official guide for Rust, without having an explicit this (e.g. stdin.readline().split("\t").sort()). Would you illustrate why it's a bad idea and how it "fragments" the API? I've made "s2i.h" an add-on header in an experimental branch for the exact purpose to learn more about these.

Like I mentioned above, it fragments your API: there is multiple ways to do the same thing. You are also basically inventing your own preprocessor-based syntax, which no tools are prepared to understand. C is at it's best when it is written as C; not when you try to make it into other language. Don't feel bad tough: all C programmers have fallen into this pit at some point in their careers. At least you haven't tried to write vtable implementation with preprocessor to make class polymorhism in C.

@user694733 I created a discussion to rid comment of irrelevant things. I invite moderators to refactor this comment section.

Are you sure your library was "too verbose"?  Can you illustrate what you mean.  The ubiquitous solo _ in the header identified by the 'terse' link in the question is puzzling.  If your function names were enormously long (more than 32 characters, pulling a limit out of thin air), then yes: using such names is unwieldy.  But the improved terseness would probably come from using appropriate, consistent, unambiguous abbreviations for words in the function names.  The C standard has strcpy() rather than unchecked_string_copy() (which is only 21 characters) — you could/should do likewise.

@JonathanLeffler Well, Vulkan and OpenGL are much more verbose than my library, that'll be half the reason that'll convince me. However, my library won't be useful if I can't make what it does easy to do. Hence the post in the linked discussion

What the C standard says specifically in C17 7.1.3 is this:


All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use, except those identifiers which are lexically identical to keywords.
All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.


In plain English, this means that:

An identifier starting with __ or _A (any uppercase letter) are reserved for the compiler and the compiler's standard library (details here: What's the meaning of "reserved for any use"?). So if you use such identifiers, you might get naming collisions with the standard library.
Any identifier starting with _ is reserved for use when you declare anything outside a function (including when you declare a function). "Tag name spaces" refers to struct/union/enum tags declared outside of a function.

So this means that you shouldn't write code such as:
// BAD
int _;
void f (void); // this function here to illustrate that _ is at file scope

or
// BAD
void _ (void);

or
// BAD
struct _ {/* ... */};
void f (void);  // this function here to illustrate that _ is at file scope

or you may get naming collisions. You may however write code like
// OK
void f (void)
{
  int _ = something;
}

or
// OK
#define x(_) _

int main() {
  int _ = x(5);
  printf("%d",_);
}

The macro parameter is not a file scope identifier but expanded and resolved inside main(). Naming a macro _ would be a problem though, since that puts _ in the ordinary name space at file scope (macro name identifiers are always visible at file scope).

That being said, naming a variable _ for any purpose is an awful idea. If you find some code too verbose then surely you can at least come up with a 3 letter identifier that's far more descriptive? val, cnt, fun, adr, tmp etc.
I've only ever seen the identifier _ used in the context of code golf, code obfuscation or "posing" of one's knowledge of meaningless exotic C features. So if you are truly contemplating of using _, know that you find yourself in one of these categories. And that's not flattering for one's code - to be butchered at the next code review.

I agree with the conclusion. Using single underscore is an antipattern, because it is one of the least visible characters in character set. Especially when using it near other small symbols, as that turns code into symbol soup that is hard to read.

@user694733 Similarly a single digit l (lower case L) is also to be avoided for the same reasons, since it looks like 1 (one) in many fonts.

Re “Naming a macro _ would be a problem though, since that puts _ in the ordinary name space at file scope”: Macro names are not in the ordinary name space and are not at file scope. Regarding scope, the file, function, function prototype, and block scopes are concepts only within phase 7 of program translation, the compilation that is conceptually after preprocessing. Macro names are processed in phase 4. Regarding name space, C 2018 6.10.3 says “… There is one name space for macro names…”

@EricPostpischil Well it's a simplified explanation. If there's a macro then it will obviously start expanding other uses of that macro name, leading to diverse strange compilation problems.

Aside from questions of whether _ is reserved for the C implementation, it is not reserved for your library. A program using your library could define it for its own purposes, either macros or identifiers with block, function, or function parameter scope or member names of structures or unions, and these could conflict with your library headers. That includes other third-party libraries that adopt the same strategy as yours and define _ for their own purposes—if a client program attempted to include both your library and the other one, there would be a conflict.
Conflicts between third-party libraries and their clients are generally avoided by choosing some distinctive prefix and using that for every identifier defined in the library that could be visible to a client.
